# java.lang.Object; cannot be cast to shoppingbasket.Product

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to retrieve a list of products with they're associated offers. After iterating through the result of the query I want to be able to use the getters/setters from the products class but I know it's not working because the query is not returning an instance of Product.

function to grab the products:

```
public List<Product> getProducts() {
    factory = (new Configuration()).configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

    Query query = session.createQuery("from Product p INNER JOIN p.offers"); 
    //The castList is declared and explained at the bottom of listing
    List<Product> list =  query.list();

    Iterator<Product> iter = list.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Product product = iter.next();
        System.out.println(product);
    }
}
```

Hibernate mapping for Offer:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="shoppingbasket.Offer" table="offers">
    <id name="offerID" type="integer" access="field">
        <column name="OfferID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="offerDescription" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="OfferDescription" length="60" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="shortDescription" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="ShortDescription" length="10" not-null="false"/>
    </property>
    <property name="TFTPOTGroup" type="java.lang.Integer" access="field">
        <column name="TFTPOTGroup" length="4" not-null="false" default="null"/>
    </property>
    <property name="discountPercentage" type="java.lang.Double" access="field">
        <column name="DiscountPercentage"  not-null="false" default="null"/>
    </property>
</class>
```

Hibernate mapping for Product:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="shoppingbasket.Product" table="products">
    <id name="productID" type="integer" access="field">
        <column name="ProductID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="offerID" type="java.lang.Integer" access="field">
        <column name="OfferID" />
    </property>
    <property name="productName" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="ProductName" length="40" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="unitPrice" type="java.math.BigDecimal" access="field">
        <column name="UnitPrice"/>
    </property>
    <one-to-one name="offers" class="shoppingbasket.Offer" />
</class>
```

Product class:

```
public class Product implements java.io.Serializable {
private Integer productID;
private Integer offerID;
private String productName;
private BigDecimal unitPrice;
private Offer offer;
public Integer getProductID() {
    return productID;
}
public void setProductID(Integer productID) {
    this.productID = productID;
}
public Integer getOfferID() {
    return this.offerID;
}
public void setOfferID(Integer offerID) {
    this.offerID = offerID;
}
public Offer getOffers() {
    return offer;
}
public void setOffers(Offer offer) {
    this.offer = offer;
}
//more getters/setters
}
```

Offer class:

```
public class Offer
{
private Integer offerID;
private String offerDescription;
private String shortDescription;
private Integer TFTPOTGroup;
private Double discountPercentage;
public Integer getOfferID() {
    return offerID;
}
public void setOfferID(Integer offerID) {
    this.offerID = offerID;
}
//more getters/setters
```

}

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#Potential Unnecessary Projections Data:`

Since you're not specifying **SELECT** clause in the query and putting **explicit joins**, hibernate will return 2 objects per row (*Product, Offers*), wherein Product object might already be populated with the Offer data due to **underlying mapping associations**.

Try adding **select** clause to the query and see if it casts correctly

```
Add SELECT p FROM ... to the query
```

Comment: Thank you, worked straight away. Have been wrecking my brain for hours